# Какие библиотеки для анализа графиков Python

Tags: python, математика, графики

Есть библиотека matplotlib, она строит графики по заданным формулам, например, 2x^2+4x-10

Мне нужно наоборот: у меня есть картинка графика, мне нужно получить эту формулу[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

здесь представлен график, мне нужна формула, по которой был задан этот график

Если уже есть статьи(английский и русский язык), предоставьте пожалуйста ссылку

Comment: это в принципе очень непростая задача и я сомневаюсь в существовании подобных библиотек. Маленький пример того, почему это сложно - представьте себе, что такой библиотеке попался на вход график функции, указанной у вас в вопросе, НО начертили ее для диапазона значений по оси X: `[-0.50, 0.50]` - представили? Сможете угадать формулу функции? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

любая непрерывная функция может быть представлена как сумма определённого кол-ва синусов (умноженных на некоторые коэффициенты) и как же вы тогда можете определить, что за функция?

ответов бесконечно много

если же говорить про самую простую функцию (содержащую наименьшее кол-во членов), то и тут не все так просто, потому что на небольшом участке области определения одинаково выглядеть может опять таки много функций

кроме того есть еще вопрос точности определения точек функции на основании картинки - это тоже будет искажать результат

в науке делается так обычно - есть экспериментальные точки, есть функция, надо найти коэффициенты (например с использованием метода наименьших квадратов как критерия и градиентного спуска как метода подбора коэффициентов)

в данном случае можно сделать так же:

1. вбить сотню разных функций и их сочетаний
2. по графику определить точки
3. подобрать коэффициенты для разных функций
4. вычислить точность (например хи-квадрат или R-квадрат) и у какой функции этот показатель будет наименьшим, та функция и подходит

P.S.

но не думаю, что есть сколько-нибудь хорошая библиотека для запрашиваемой задачи, разве что руками